# Read cells from Excel file in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, phpexcel

i am using Laravel Excel v2.1.* for Laravel 5

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    $rows = Excel::load('storage\\app\\demo.xlsx')->ignoreEmpty()->skip(1)->get();
  echo "<pre>";
        print_r($rows->toArray());
        echo "</pre>";
  });
```

if my excel file have first row as heading and then values then its working fine.

[image]

but i have excel file where first row of the excel file are have merged cells .so is there any option to read cell by cell

but my excel files first row is having

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to read this file out differently, you can't use the simple import methods. You have to read it out per coordinate, example of the native PHPExcel methods:

http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/phpexcel_library/1.7.4/manual.html#_Toc237519900

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you. This is from the link that Reiah Paul Sam wrote. It's a loop to read all the cells of the excel file.

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('storage\\app\\demo.xlsx');
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
echo '<table>' . "\n";
foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    echo '<tr>' . "\n";

    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();

    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); // This loops all cells,
    // even if it is not set.
    // By default, only cells
    // that are set will be
    // iterated.
    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {

        echo '<td>' . $cell->getValue() . '</td>' . "\n";

    }

     echo '</tr>' . "\n";

}

echo '</table>' . "\n";
```

Note that maybe you will need the zip extension enable in your php.ini

I hope that this help.
Best Regards.